# Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user. Unable to Connect to Remote Database using Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have been trying to connect to remote database using NodeJS where I have also added a user and given all the permission.

I am getting this Error:

> **ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user.**

Please help.
This is the code

```
const mySql = require("mysql");

//creating  DataBase connection
const con = mySql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.SQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.SQL_USER,
  password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.SQL_DATABASE
});

//connect to  DataBase
con.connect(function(err)
{
  if(err)
  {
      console.log("Error Connecting to Database: "+err);
  }
  else
  {
      console.log("Connected to Database: Successful");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I Found the answer, Add to remote Access mySql in your Cpanel your local IP so that you can access it. Thanks

Comment: thanks this helped me out as well!